# How do I pull contents from a .txt file and display a random line of it in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Being a noob at HTML, I only know a solution to this in C#. I'm just trying to separate each line of the .txt so I can randomly pull lines from it and display them when a button is pressed. In addition, rather than using a submit button, I wanted to create a div of my own styled button for the user to press. (Which I know how to do) and use a jQuery 'on click'.

I'm a little unsure how to describe exactly what I'm trying to do, but I hope I did it well enough.

Thank you guys in advance.

**Note** This is the C# I used to create a relatively simple Trivia game. In a separate Trivia.cs I had split the question and answers from each other (In the .txt they were separated by an *)

I'm not sure if this will help guide anyone, however.

static List GetTriviaList()
        {
            //Get Contents from the file.  Remove the special char "\r".  Split on each line.  Convert to a list.
            List contents = File.ReadAllText("trivia.txt").Replace("\r", "").Split('\n').ToList();

```
        //Each item in list "contents" is now one line of the Trivia.txt document.

        //make a new list to return all trivia questions
        List<Trivia> returnList = new List<Trivia>();
        // TODO: go through each line in contents of the trivia file and make a trivia object.
        //       add it to our return list.
        // Example: Trivia newTrivia = new Trivia("what is my name?*question");
        //Return the full list of trivia questions
        foreach (var item in contents)
        {
            Trivia bestTrivia = new Trivia(item);
            returnList.Add(bestTrivia);
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

Comment: Will the *.txt* file already be on the server, or will it be something that the user provides at runtime? Also, if you could provide the JavaScript that you already have written (and possibly the applicable segments of the C# as well), that would help us guide you in the right direction.

Comment: The .txt is already in the server. I apologize for not having said that clearer. As far as what I've already written, It's just me jerking around trying to pretend I understand what I'm doing more than I actually do. As for the C#, I'll edit the body.

Comment: I believe it requires PHP, but I'm not quite sure as I've never done it before.

Comment: Javascript exucutes on the users browser, the text file is on the server. This should give you hint to the problem you have. You basically have 2 options: serverside with asp.net/c# or use AJAX to acceess the file by javascript. If you're going to open the file via ajax I suggest storing the data as JSON

Comment: Another pertinant question is what is the size of the file? If it is not too big, use ASP.net/C# to inluded it in the page as a data object, again preferably as a JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working Plunker showing how you could do it with just JavaScript (using the jQuery library).

http://plnkr.co/edit/BUCZOKd0MFDsa2jdMkJs?p=preview

The basic process is as follows:

1. Fetch the text file from the server
2. Split it into an array of lines
3. When the user clicks the button, generate a random number
4. Display the line corresponding to the random number

Here's the JavaScript for that (see the Plunker above for full source):

```
var lines;
var randomNumber;
var lastRandomNumber;

$(document.body).ready(function () {

  // load the trivia from the server
  $.ajax({
    url: 'trivia.txt'
  }).done(function(content) {

    // normalize the line breaks, then split into lines
    lines = content.replace(/\r\n|\r/g, '\n').trim().split('\n');

    // only set up the click handler if there were lines found
    if (lines && lines.length) {
      $('#showLine').on('click', function () {
        // loop to prevent repeating the last random number
        while (randomNumber === lastRandomNumber) {
          randomNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * lines.length);
          // check to prevent infinite loop
          if (lines.length === 1) { break; }
        }
        // keep track of the last random number
        lastRandomNumber = randomNumber;

        // show the corresponding line
        $('#trivia').text(lines[randomNumber]);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:** Added some explanatory comments to the JavaScript (updated above and in the Plunker). Also added a check to prevent getting the same random line twice in a row.

Comment: This really helped. I've gotta do a few modifications because currently, it won't cycle through my text doc. (I feel like I don't have it in the correct place in my files)

But again, thank you!

Comment: Hi there. what line do i change to make the script do the "random function" every time the page loads? this script seems to be the simplest i found and work but need to change every time the page loads - I don't know JavaScript but tried to pay with .on('onload' and .on('load',  -- just don't know enough to get it working

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to use server-side language, like PHP. Otherwise you will not be able to read only one word or string from the file. The javascript works in browser and to parse a file, as a first step, it would need the file fully loaded into the browser.

PS

Based on the task I would not recommend you to use JQuery or Javascript. Most likely this task would mean a protection, as in early years, this way was used to activate a copy of purchased software.
Presumably, the soft was bought with instruction and the activation algorithm demand word from instruction pointing page number, row number and number of the word in a row. In the case of Javascript - all this mechanism would be working on client site. It would need to load the file fully and parse it in browser where every one would debug it and extract the secret text fully. It would be an easy to crack protection.